# Query multiple google sheets in different sheets with sheet name in column1

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-query-language

I need help to show column 1 to get where sheet it came from, my current formula contains this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
{Product1!$AZ2:$AZ&"Product1",Product1!$A2:$AS};
{Product2!$AZ2:$AZ&"Product2",Product2!$A2:$AS}},"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4
WHERE Col1 is not null 
LABEL Col2 'Date', 
Col3 'Data1', Col4 'Data2'"))
```

what's the code I am missing? Column 1 should contain either Product 1 and Product 2 depending on which row. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Col1 into select:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
{Product1!$AZ2:$AZ&"Product1",Product1!$A2:$AS};
{Product2!$AZ2:$AZ&"Product2",Product2!$A2:$AS}},"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
WHERE Col1 is not null 
LABEL Col2 'Date', 
Col3 'Data1', Col4 'Data2'"))
```

Comment: thank you that works.. and I have to move each Col# since I am adding a new column, and added Col1 'Product Name', before Col2 'Date'